# How to replace the True and False to numerical values under specific conditions in Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to convert the True and False to specific values in a DataFrame. I am looking to replace all times in the "time" variable in seconds which are less than 300 with a specific number, for example "1". Any number comes after any number (which is less than 300 second) more than 300 seconds will get the same specific number '1'. Any number comes after that number (which is higher than 300 seconds) should be always less than 300 seconds and get another specific number, for example "2" and etc.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime (df['timestamp']) 
df['delta'] = (df['timestamp']-df['timestamp'].shift())
df['time'] = df['delta'].dt.total_seconds()
df['outlier'] =  df['time'] > 300
df['Column1'] = np.where(df['outlier'], np.where(df['time'] > 300, '1','1'),'na')
```

This is the input. This a sample of the DataFrame which I have:

```
    timestamp              delta            time     outlier   output 
 
0  2020-11-08 17:54:53       NaT              NaN      False      na 
1  2020-11-08 17:54:56   0 days 00:00:03      3.0      False      na 
2  2020-11-08 17:54:57   0 days 00:00:01      1.0      False      na 
3  2020-11-08 21:04:41   0 days 03:09:44    11384.0    True       1   
4  2020-11-08 21:04:52   0 days 00:00:11      11.0     False      na 
5  2020-11-08 21:04:53   0 days 00:00:01      1.0      False      na   
6  2020-11-10 20:36:32   1 days 23:31:39   171099.0    True       1   
7  2020-11-10 20:37:01   0 days 00:00:29      29.0     False      na 
8  2020-11-10 20:37:04   0 days 00:00:03      3.0      False      na
```

This is the actual output I am looking for:

```
     timestamp              delta            time     outlier   output 
 
0  2020-11-08 17:54:53       NaT              NaN      False     NaN 
1  2020-11-08 17:54:56   0 days 00:00:03      3.0      False      1  
2  2020-11-08 17:54:57   0 days 00:00:01      1.0      False      1  
3  2020-11-08 21:04:41   0 days 03:09:44    11384.0    True       1  
4  2020-11-08 21:04:52   0 days 00:00:11      11.0     False      2  
5  2020-11-08 21:04:53   0 days 00:00:01      1.0      False      2    
6  2020-11-10 20:36:32   1 days 23:31:39   171099.0    True       2    
7  2020-11-10 20:37:01   0 days 00:00:29      29.0     False      3    
8  2020-11-10 20:37:04   0 days 00:00:03      3.0      False      3
```

Please note that this is just a sample of the Dataframe so please help me to fix the code above and lets it works for a Dataframe has big numbers of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
df['output'] = (df.outlier.cumsum() + 1).map(str).shift()
```

If you prefer integers:

```py
df['output'] = (df.outlier.cumsum() + 1).map(int).astype(object).shift()
```